# Call contentdocument of object OnInit

Tags: angular, svg

I have the following in my Angular component:

```
<object data="../../assets/drawing.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
id="svgSF" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

However, when I do the following snippet:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    var svgSF:any=document.getElementById('svgSF');
    console.log(svgSF.contentDocument);
  }
```

It returns me an empty document:

`<html>  <body>  </body> </html>`

If I do this in my Chrome's debugger it returns me the svg document. Does the object is still not initialized in my `OnInit` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move this logic into `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to use onload method on the svg element, like this:

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log("-- AfterViewInit --");
    var svgSF:any=document.getElementById('svgSF');
    svgSF.onload = () => {
        console.log(svgSF.contentDocument);
    } 
  }
}
```